# Lua Socket Send 200 OK close connection

Tags: http, nginx, lua, openresty, http-1.1

What is minimal HTTP 200 OK Connection close response for Nginx/lua/openresty. I have:

```
local sock, err = ngx.req.socket(true)
sock:send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\\r\\nConnection: close\\r\\n\\r\\n")
```

and curl says:

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a case of no response body, you should probably use [204 No Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204) response code; "201 Created" may be an option as well for requests that create resources.

Also: replace each double slash with a single one, as you don't need to escape slash to generate `CR LF` sequence.

Comment: I have a problem even  with 5 letter content like “hello”

Comment: Replace each double slash with a single one.